# Error while sending INIT_DB packet. PID=7060

Tags: php, exception, web-crawler

While the following function was executing, I got an exception thrown after which I got this error:

> Error while sending INIT_DB packet. PID=7060

And then the script gave several warnings of:

> mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource

FUNCTION:

```
private function initiateChildCrawler($parent_Url_Html) {

        global $CFG;
        static $foundLink;
        static $parentID;
        static $urlToCrawl_InstanceOfChildren;

        $foundLinkArray = array();
        $tempHtml = $parent_Url_Html->getHTML();
        $foundLinkCount = 0;
        foreach($tempHtml->find('a') as $foundLinkArray[$foundLinkCount++]);

        $anotherArray = array();
        $x = 0;     
        for($i = 0; $i<$foundLinkCount; $i++) {
            $anotherArray[$x++] = $foundLinkArray[$i]->href;            
        }

        foreach($anotherArray as $foundLink) 
        {
            $foundLink = url_to_absolute($parent_Url_Html->getURL(), $foundLink);

            if($this->validateEduDomain($foundLink)) 
            {
                $parentID = $this->loadSaveInstance->parentExists_In_URL_DB_CRAWL($this->returnParentDomain($foundLink));
                if($parentID != FALSE) 
                {
                    if($this->loadSaveInstance->checkUrlDuplication_In_URL_DB_CRAWL($foundLink) == FALSE)
                    {
                        $urlToCrawl_InstanceOfChildren = new urlToCrawl($foundLink);
                        if($urlToCrawl_InstanceOfChildren->getSimpleDomSource($CFG->finalContext)!= FALSE)
                        {                           
                            try {
                                $this->loadSaveInstance->url_db_html($urlToCrawl_InstanceOfChildren->getURL(), $urlToCrawl_InstanceOfChildren->getHTML());
                                $this->loadSaveInstance->saveCrawled_To_URL_DB_CRAWL(NULL, $foundLink, "crawled", $parentID);
                            } catch (DbException $e) {
                                echo "<br><br>Exception Catched on line 303!!!<br><br>";
                                echo "The link where the exception was thrown was: {$foundLink}<br>";
                                if(strstr($e->getMessage(), 'MySQL server has gone away')) {
                                    $this->connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
                                    mysql_select_db("crawler1", $this->connection);
                                }                               
                            }                                               
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

The particular URL that is causing the exception is: http://www.ashford.edu/student_services/deanslist.htm

I am clueless about this. Please help.

Comment: I am getting the same error....

Comment: @Fabrizio while doing same type of crawling of some other stuff?

Comment: I get it randomly when the server has has about 100-150 concurrent connections (limit is set to 1000, and CPU usage is less than 2-3%)

Comment: Have you found any working solution for that??

Comment: I tweaked lots of settings in MySQL and it seems like it is working.  Maybe you want to check your indexes and see if maybe the queries take too long or you have too many open connections and that is why it starts to give you this error.  Something else that I have noticed is that the space in /tmp was getting really low during those errors (temporary tables)

Comment: Try to kill that process